# Why segmentation fault (core dumped) when I cin a string into node->name?

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault, malloc

Segmentation fault (core dumped) when I `getline(cin, node->name)`.

I fixed by declare a `str` string in my input function, then `node->name = str`. But ran to the line `cin >> node->year` and still hit Segmentation fault.

```cpp
struct client
{
    int code;
    string name;
    int year;
    float maths, physics, chemistry;
    struct client *next;
};

struct client* input()
{
    struct client *node = (struct client *)malloc(sizeof(struct client));

    cout << "Code: ";
    cin >> node->code;

    cout << "Name: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, node->name);

    cout << "Year: ";
    cin >> node->year;

    cout << "Maths, Physics, Chemistry: ";
    cin >> node->maths >> node->physics >> node->chemistry;

    node->next = NULL;

    return node;
}
```

Comment: This is not [tag:c].

Comment: By casting `malloc`ed memory, you are bypassing calling the constructor on your `node`. So it is not legal to do anything with it.

Comment: I have a question regarding `getline`: does it takes an initialized string, or does it take care of initializing it itself ? Because that can be the source of the bug (genuie question)

Comment: @BoBTFish Not quite: It’s legal to call its constructor, via placement-new.

Comment: @joH1 If it's not initialized, it's not a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you use `malloc` to allocate your memory, nothing in the new `node` will be initialized. In particular `string name` won't be initialized properly and that will cause problems when you try to use it, because any functionality involving it relies on the fact that the string has been properly constructed. Instead of this:

```
struct client *node = (struct client *)malloc(sizeof(struct client));
```

Do this:

```
client *node = new client;
```

This way the `node` (and the `name`) within are properly initialized.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments are hinting at, your `string` probably refers to [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), which is a non-POD class. This means you need to call the constructor etc. to use the object, not just allocate the memory.

This means that you have to do instead:

```
client *node = new node;
```

And similarly, to destruct it:

```
delete node;
```

Or, better, use a RAII pointer type like [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) in C++11:

```
std::unique_ptr<client> = std::make_unique<client>();
```

Answer (score 1):

We have two alternatives in addition to those already mentioned in other answers.

---

The recommended way is to refactor your code and avoid dynamic allocation.
Use automatic variables and move semantics instead.

```
client input()
{
  client node;
  // ... do input
  return node;
}
```

(You can use `client` directly in place of `struct client`)

This is the preferred way in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

---

If you insist on `malloc`, then call the constructor explicitly via placement-new:

```
client* node = (client*) malloc(sizeof(client));
new (node) client{};
```

And when you `free` it, remember to call the destructor:

```
node->~client();
free(node);
```

This approach is extremely error-prone and counter-intuitive
and is strongly discouraged.